# Ruby convert IDN domain from Punycode to Unicode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, idn

I'm writing a Rails app that needs to convert an IDN domain name from Punycode into its Unicode equivalent. I tried installing the [idn gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/idn) that has bindings to GNU LibIDN, but it won't compile the native code. Apparently [others](http://isitruby19.com/idn) have the same issue with Ruby 1.9.x.

I also tried the pure Ruby [SimpleIDN gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/simpleidn), but I would prefer something native.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the [simpleidn gem](https://github.com/mmriis/simpleidn). It works with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2.

Edit your Gemfile:

```
gem 'simpleidn'
```

then you can enter the command as follows:

```
SimpleIDN.to_unicode("xn--mllerriis-l8a.com")
=> "møllerriis.com"

SimpleIDN.to_ascii("møllerriis.com")
=> "xn--mllerriis-l8a.com"
```

Answer (score 3):

Whoops - looks like I found a capable answer shortly after posting (sorry).  There is a subtly placed [patch](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=28573&group_id=924&atid=3635) from 09/2010 in the bug reports section of the [project's RubyForge page](http://rubyforge.org/projects/idn/).  Adding this to my Gemfile now allows me to use the idn library:

```
gem 'idn', '~> 0.0.2', :git => 'git://github.com/mihu/idn'
```

Too bad that the gem is apparently abandoned :/

Comment: Maybe you want to maintain the gem, would be nice.

Comment: @asaaki I totally would, but I'm still a Ruby noob. Maybe someday :)

Answer (score 2):

The [`Dnsruby::Name`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dnsruby/Dnsruby/Name) class with the method [`.punicode`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/dnsruby/Dnsruby/Name#punycode-class_method) of the [`Dnsruby`](https://github.com/alexdalitz/dnsruby) lib allows you to convert an IDN domain from Unicode UTF-8 to ASCII punycode:

```rb
Dnsruby::Name.punycode('.cf')
# => "xn--en8h.cf"
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/knu/ruby-domain_name seem to have exactly the same functionality:

```
irb(main):018:0> SimpleIDN::Punycode.encode('axa.test')
=> "axa.test-"

irb(main):017:0> DomainName::Punycode.encode('axa.test')
=> "axa.test-"
```